# VSCodeでマウスホバー時の「MDN Reference」表示までの時間を変更したい

Tags: vscode

Visual Studio Codeでマウスホバーの際に出る「MDN Reference information」の表示されるまでのタイミング(秒数)を変更出来ないでしょうか？

非表示にする方法は見当たるのですが、時間を変更したいと思いました。

[Visual Studio CodeのReference informationを非表示にする方法 - Qiita](https://qiita.com/unsoluble_sugar/items/6985aba97a5a89ca609f)

Answer (score 1):

editor hover delay でなんとかならないでしょうか？

Comment: なりそうな感じですね。[Is there a way to disable "MDN References Intellisense" popup (for HTML & CSS) in VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59162276/9014308)